trying to use 'struct hostnet' from netdb.h, but it's saying 'invalid use of undefined type
I'm writing in STM32CubeIDE v1.15.0 for a Nucleo-F756ZG
I want to get a timestamp from a NTP server and I found a guide with a link to this code: https://github.com/lettier/ntpclient/blob/master/source/c/main.c
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; // Server address data structure.
    struct hostent \*server;      // Server data structure.

    int sockfd = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP ); // Create a UDP socket.
    
    if ( sockfd < 0 )
      printf( "ERROR opening socket" );
    
    server = gethostbyname( "pool.ntp.org" ); // Convert URL to IP.
    
    if ( server == NULL )
        printf( "ERROR, no such host" );
    
    // Zero out the server address structure.
    
    bzero( ( char* ) &serv_addr, sizeof( serv_addr ) );
    
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    
    // Copy the server's IP address to the server address structure.
    bcopy( ( char* )server->h_addr, ( char* ) &serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length );
    
    // Convert the port number integer to network big-endian style and save it to the server address structure.
    int portno = 123; // NTP UDP port number.
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons( portno );

The problem that I have is that I do not understand why here bcopy( ( char\* )server-\>h_addr, ( char\* ) &serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server-\>h_length ); it gives me this error invalid use of undefined type 'struct hostent' while there is not a problem here server = gethostbyname( "pool.ntp.org" ); // Convert URL to IP I included the netdb.h library and is not giving me any errors there so that s a confusing part for me cuz I thought it might be a linker error.
My question is: what is the source of this problem? how can I fix it? OR if you can point me to another implementation of getting a timestamp from a NTP server.
I tried changing the bcopy function to memcpy(&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server-\>h_addr, server-\>h_length);, but it didn't do nothing, I tried to move the #include \<netdb.h\> in every file that made sense

You should check the header file to see if the definition of the structure has been commented out, or otherwise made unavailable.

@OldBoy I checked the header file, the code is not commented, but before it is #if LWIP_DNS_API_DECLARE_STRUCTS that i do not know how does it works

The code you show is incomplete.  Please show the exact code you're attempting to compile, and copy/paste the exact compiler command and output.

@dbush I  do not understand what more code do you want, i dont believe you need more and if you want more is in the link i added.

The problem is that struct hostent has been disabled in netdb,h for some reason, by that #if statement. I am not sure if this is Linux or Windows, but I have checked both version that I am able to access and neither one includes that statement. Are you using some non-standard libraries?

@OldBoy i use windows, and the libraries that came with the installation of the ide, I didn't had a C++ environment before this ,no compiler, no libraries, I commented the if but it still gives the same error

I found a version of netdb.h in github that includes that #if statement. I suggest you add the following line before all your #include statements in your source file: #define LWIP_DNS_API_DECLARE_STRUCTS 1.

netdb.h has #ifndef LWIP_DNS_API_DECLARE_STRUCTS #define LWIP_DNS_API_DECLARE_STRUCTS 1 #endif, so struct hostent should be defined unless LWIP_DNS_API_DECLARE_STRUCTS has been defined as 0 in lwipopts.h.

@IanAbbott sadly there is no LWIP_DNS_API_DECLARE_STRUCTS in lwipopts.h, but yes in netdb.h is all that #ifndef define 1

There is nothing "sad" about LWIP_DNS_API_DECLARE_STRUCTS not being defined in lwipopts.h. It just means the default setting is not being overridden (at least not being overridden by that file).

@IanAbbott LWIP_DNS_API_DECLARE_STRUCTS  is just in the netdb.h file, #ifndef LWIP_DNS_API_DECLARE_STRUCTS #define LWIP_DNS_API_DECLARE_STRUCTS  1 #endif, #if LWIP_DNS_API_DECLARE_STRUCTS

You're probably supposed to add -DLWIP_DNS_API_DECLARE_STRUCTS to the command line when compiling. Put that in your makefile.

@Barmar I do not think I have a makefile, and I'm compiling it by the build button of the IDE im not using a cli

There should be somewhere that you can specify the options to use when compiling in the IDE. Sorry, I can't be any more specific.
